# Debug for generic types in Rust

Tags: rust

I am learning rust and I wanted to make a small helper lib to parse a file and cast the content as `Vec<T>`. My idea is to use it like that: `file_to_vec::<u32>("path/to/file")`

I was doing that for now:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::fs::{read_to_string};

pub fn file_to_vec<T>(path: &str) -> Vec<T> where T: FromStr {
    return read_to_string(path)
        .expect("Error reading input")
        .trim()
        .split("\n")
        .map(|line| line.parse::<T>().unwrap())
        .collect();
}
```

The compiler is saying:
`<T as FromStr>::Err cannot be formatted using {:?} because it doesn't implement Debug`

I will have to implement it but I don't know how.

```
impl<T> fmt::Debug {
 ???
}
```

I tried to read the documentation [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) but it was not helping

Comment: Nitpicks: The compiler can infer the `T` in `parse::<T>()`, you don't need to specify it, and using explicit `return` at tail position is bad style. Also, I'd take `&Path` or `impl AsRef<Path>` instead of a `&str`, but using `&str` is also fine.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.
I removed the type specification and You are right it works fine.
About the return: Is it a bad practice or just a common way to not use it?

Comment: A bad practice, as the common way is to not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) requires the error type to implement [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) because it prints it if an error occurred.

The solution is to require the error type to be `Debug`. The error type is `<T as FromStr>::Err` or simply `T::Err`, so:

```rust
pub fn file_to_vec<T>(path: &str) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: FromStr,
    T::Err: Debug,
{
    return read_to_string(path)
        .expect("Error reading input")
        .trim()
        .split("\n")
        .map(|line| line.parse::<T>().unwrap())
        .collect();
}
```